# SQL Database - FIRST Operand

Tags: sql, database

Here are my database relations:

shows(showID, title, premiere_year, network, creator, category)

episode(showID, episodeID, airdate, title)

- showID is a foreign key to shows

actor(actID, fname, lname)

main_cast(showID, actID, role)

- showID is a foreign key to shows actID is a foreign key to actor

recurring_cast(showID, episodeID, actID, role)

showID is a foreign key to shows episodeID is a foreign key to episode

- actID is a foreign key to actor

customer(custID, fname, lname, email, creditcard,membersince,renewaldate, password, username)

cust_queue(custID, showID, datequeued)

- custID is a foreign key to customer showID is a foreign key to shows

watched(custID, showID, episodeID, datewatched)

- custID is a foreign key to customer
- showID is a foreign key to shows
- (showID, episodeID) is a foreign key to episode
- (custID, showID) is a foreign key to cust_queue

### All the 'IDs' are primary keys

I have queries I was given and for some, I don't know how to go about it. Such as:

For each customer (display first and last name), display which show and episode was the first one watched by that customer. Sort the result by customer's last name.

I'm trying:

```
{
SELECT FIRST (Watched.datewatched)
FROM Watched
WHERE Watched.datewatched

IN

(SELECT Customer.fname, Customer.lname, Shows.title, Episode.title 
FROM Customer, Shows, Episode, Watched
WHERE Shows.showid = Episode.showID AND Watched.custID = Customer.custID AND Watched.showID = Shows.showid
ORDER BY Watched.datewatched);
}
```

But I don't think that's right. Any ideas?? I don't think I know how to use the 'FIRST' operand.

Comment: Why is this tagged php? Also it's missing a correct database tag - oracle, sql-server, etc.

Comment: There is no first operand!  This is why you don't know how to use it.

Comment: So how do I get the first show watched by a customer?

Comment: use group by.  in sql you have to think in sets not as functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't give a platform I will use code that should work on most (all) SQL platforms:

Here is how to solve a problem like this, take it in steps.  First we want to know the first show and episode watch by a user.

**Find the first show watched by user**

```
select custID, showID, min(datewatched)
from watched
group by custID, showID
```

**now get the first episode of that show**

```
select firstshow.custID, firstshow.showID, firstshow.datewatched, minDW, mineID
from ( 
  select custID, showID, min(datewatched) as minDW
  from watched
  group by custID, showID
) as firstshow
join 
(
  select custID, showID, datewatched, min(episodeID) as mineID
  from watched
  group by custID, showID, datewatched
) as firstepisode on firstshow.custID = firstepisode.custID 
                 and firstshow.showID = firstepisode.showID
                 and firstshow.minDW = firstepisode.datewatched
```

**now join back to get the username and show name**

```
select customer.fname, customer.lname, shows.Title as show, mineID as EpisodeNum
from ( 
  select custID, showID, min(datewatched) as minDW
  from watched
  group by custID, showID
) as firstshow
join 
(
  select custID, showID, datewatched, min(episodeID) as mineID
  from watched
  group by custID, showID, datewatched
) as firstepisode on firstshow.custID = firstepisode.custID 
                 and firstshow.showID = firstepisode.showID
                 and firstshow.minDW = firstepisode.datewatched
join customer on firstshow.custID = customer.custID
join shows on firstshow.showID = shows.showID
order by customer.lname
```

Even something complicated like this can be simple if you take it by steps.

Comment: this kind of helps but in the second part of your code, where did 'firstshow' come from?

Comment: firstshow is an alias for the sub-query explained in the first part of the answer.  you can think of it as using a select statement to define a table.

Comment: @BrettSaguid - unless you are using db2, oracle or sql server and can use the `OVER ()` statement, you have to use a sub-query to solve this problem.  It is very easy and "simple" if you can use over however.

Comment: Sorry, Im extremely new the SQL, but where did you define the first part of the code to be 'firstshow'?

Comment: The stuff in the () - you should read Sql basics, I can't teach you sql in comments

Comment: Actually I wasn't reading your code correctly!! Thanks this helped a lot!